# ManualResetEvent stopping socket program in windows service after sometime

Tags: c#, sockets, events, windows-services

I have a windows service which is monitoring a Socket using TCP/IP protocol.As per my requirement my code is establishing a connection to the Machine and receiving data from there and this i want continuously,that's why i have made it in windows service.But the problem that i am facing is that, the service is reading socket ports for 3-4 hours after that automatically stops reading from the port whereas my service status from Services.msc shows its running.

Here is my code for windows Service..

```
    string ipaddress, textfileSaveLocation;
    Byte[] bBuf;
    string buf;
    Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    private System.Threading.Thread _thread;
    private ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    string df = "";

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void OnDebug()
    {
        OnStart(null);
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _thread = new Thread(DoWork);
        _thread.Start();

    }
    private void DoWork()
    {
        // create and monitor socket here...

        ipaddress = "192.168.1.100";
        int port = int.Parse("8181");

        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        string stringData;
        string input;

        IPAddress ipadd = IPAddress.Parse(ipaddress);
        IPEndPoint ipend = new IPEndPoint(ipadd, port);

        sock.NoDelay = false;
        try
        {            
            sock.Connect(ipend);
        }
        catch (Exception dfg)
       {

            return;
        }
        try
        {
            input = "Client here";
            sock.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input));

            while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
            {                  
                data = new byte[1024];
                int recv = sock.Receive(data);
                stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception DFGFD)
        {
        }

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        sock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        sock.Close();

        _shutdownEvent.Set();
        _thread.Join();  // wait for thread to stop
    }
}
}
```

Why is my service stopping receiving data after 3-4 hours ?Please help me to resolve this.

Here is my code to insert ServerMachine data into text file..

```
                        try
                        {
                            FileStream fs = new FileStream(textfileSaveLocation, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                            StreamWriter swr = new StreamWriter(textfileSaveLocation,true);
                            swr.WriteLine(stringData);
                            swr.Close();
                            swr.Dispose();
                            fs.Close();
                            fs.Dispose();
                        }
                        catch (Exception Ex)
                        {

                        }
```

Comment: Two obvious mistakes.  There's no Reset() call in this program, so after stopping the service you'll never get it started again.  And there's no protection against exceptions, sockets are pretty good at raising exceptions.  The service will just terminate and nobody can hear it scream.

Comment: @HansPassant How to add Reset() call in the given windows service.

Comment: The Set() method stops the thread.  So the Reset() method should be called before you start it.  Put it in your OnStart() method.  Keep this as a console mode program for a while until you've ironed out all the bugs and have some confidence that it is going to work okay as a service.

Comment: @HansPassant just for clarification u mean i should add _shutdownEvent.Reset(); into the start of OnStart() method?

Comment: @HansPassant How to handle exception in this case .Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @nobugz has pointed out, you have two problems.

First, you're swallowing any exceptions that occur in `DoWork()`.  You're catching them, yes, but you're not reporting them.  Why does it stop after a few hours?  Well, the server might have closed, which would terminate your socket connection.  You're not attempting to reconnect, so the thread exits, but the process continues to run.  Put some exception reporting in to see why the socket is closing and then handle it accordingly.

And this leads to the second point, namely you have no recovery capability.  Once an exception occurs or the socket is gracefully closed for some reason, your thread exits.  If you want this to work continually, then you'll need to add logic that attempts to reconnect in the cases where something goes wrong.  In other words, the only reason that `DoWork()` exits is due to a shutdown event.  Otherwise, it will need to loop, attempting to reconnect when errors occur.  As @nobugz said, this will also require you to reset the `ManualResetEvent` so that your receive loop will work as expected when a reconnect occurs.  However, you do not need to call `Reset()` in the `OnStart()` callback because you've initialized `_shutdownEvent` to `false`, which is what `Reset()` does.

HTH.

### EDIT:

This is off the cuff, so I won't verify its accuracy. I'll fix any problem you (or others) may find.

Define a `ManualResetEvent` object for shutdown notification. Change the `OnStart()` callback to this:

```
using System.Threading;

ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
Thread _thread;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // Create the thread and start it.
    _thread = new Thread(DoWork);
    _thread.Start();
}
```

Since you're wanting a TCP connection, I would strongly recommend using [`TcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as opposed to `Socket`.  Change your `DoWork()` callback to something like this:

```
using System.Net.Sockets;

private void DoWork()
{
    while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

        try
        {
            // This is a blocking call.  You might want to consider one of the
            // asynchronous methods...
            client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.100"), 8181));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the error here.
            client.Close();
            continue;
        }

        try
        {
            using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
            {
                byte[] notify = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Client here");
                stream.Write(notify, 0, notify.Length);

                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
                {
                    int numBytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    if (numBytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        string msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, numBytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the error here.
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in the OnStop() callback, trigger the thread to shutdown:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    _shutdownEvent.Set();  // trigger the thread to stop
    _thread.Join();        // wait for thread to stop
}
```

Now, it is very important to understand that TCP communication is stream-based.  What this means is that you are not guaranteed to receive a complete message each time you do a read of the socket (e.g., `TcpClient`).  If the server sends back the message *"Client notification received"*, reading the socket initially might only get *"Client noti"*.  A subsequent read might get *"fication recei"*.  A third read might get *"ved"*.  It's up to you to buffer the reads together and then process the message.  Most protocols will use some kind of header that indicates the type and length of the message.  If you're simply using strings, the type of message won't matter since everything's a string.  Further, knowing where the string ends could be done using a null terminator instead of prepending the length for example.  Just know that reading a TCP socket may only get a portion of the message you're expecting to receive.

Comment: Thanks a lot! for suggestion sir.It will completely solve my issue if you just give me a suggestion how to handle the exception nicely in this situation if it is caught.I am very novice developer trying to grasp the technology.

Comment: while (!_shutdownEvent.Wait(0)) should be  while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))

Comment: I am getting error at this line also                             int numBytesRead = client.Read(data, 0, data.Length); as Read() is not recognizing as function

Comment: It should be `stream.Read(...)` instead.  Fixed that in the code.

Comment: I need clarification catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the error here.
            client.Close();
            continue;
        }
 Will this code try to reestablish the socket connection in case any exception occurs while execution of DoWork() Method?

Comment: Yes.  The existing client will be closed as good housekeeping demands.  The `continue` statement will jump to the start of the while loop.  If the shutdown event has not been set, it'll create a new socket via `TcpClient` and attempt to reconnect.  The only way to get out of the loop is to set the shutdown event.  That is by design.

Comment: Hii @Matt Need your help again..Actually i want to save "msg" into text file for which i have written code in try catch block(Please see the code block in post that i updated) ,but what is happening here in this case that after sometime there is no data entered into the text file while data is getting read from the machine,this i can say because there is no data storage in the buffer of the machine.I guess may be any error is coming in the writing of the data to the text file in the try catch block and i am not able to handle it properly.Please help me to resolve this..

Comment: Also sir sometimes,last string is getting added into the text file continuously as if infinite loop came into ,the updated code is all that i have added to save data into text file.